# How to setup KeyPress in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jinternalframe

Can anyone help me to set a `KeyPress` action on a currently opened `jInternalFrame`?

I have a `jDesktopPane` inside a `jframe`, and I have multiple `jInternalFrame` inside the `DesktopPane`. I am using Netbeans to create this application.

On the `jDesktopPane` I have 3 buttons to open 3 `jInternalFrame`, and I created a `Keypress` on those buttons and it works fine using this code:

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F3){
        frmLogistics.setVisible(true);
        frmLogistics.toFront();
    }
}
```

A `jInternalFrame` is open and inside there's a `jtoolbar` with sets of buttons, one of it is a close button to close that opened `jInternalFrame`. I set up the code for its `ActionPerform` so when a user clicks that button the frame or window will be closed.

The problem now is how about a keyboard press? I want to trigger that close button inside the toolbar in a internalframe in order to close it

I tried this code:

```
  private void btnCloseLogisticsKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F4){
         int type = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
        int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"Do You Want to Log Out?","Exit Logistics System", type);
        if(choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            frmLogistics.setVisible(false);
            frmLogIn.show();
            btnCashier.setEnabled(false);
            btnTrucking.setEnabled(false);
            btnAccounting.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. I tried to put that code inside `jtoolbar`, `jInternalFrame` and still nothing happens. Maybe anyone of you could help me?

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks your tip works perfectly. about the third one I'll Keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

In the event keypress click right  in the Jframe de netbeans mas naki..

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:

     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F4){
   dispose();

}
```